# Binding not working inside a <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I can not get the binding of a text property for a `DataTemplate` in MVVM design pattern.
To show the problem I expose below a simplification of my problem, where I bind two different view properties to the same model property (aka `AnObject.Text`).
My code in `MainWindow.xaml` is:

```
...
<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding ButtonText}" />
...
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
               <Label Content="aaaaa" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}" />
            </DockPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
...
```

My code behind in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` (which sets the same `DataContext` for `Button` and every item in `<ItemsControl ItemsSource>`):

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

My code in `MainWindowViewModel.cs` is:

```
...
public ObservableCollection<object> MyItems => MyConverter.GetCollection(MyData.List);
public string ItemText => "dddd"; //  this DOES works
public string ItemText => AnObject.Text; // this does NOT work
...
public string ButtonText => AnObject.Text; // this DOES works (note, same object property!)
...
```

Any idea why my binding inside the `DataTemplate` does not work?

Comment: Do you really want each item to show the same text (the value of `ItemText`)?

Comment: it is only an example to try solving the issue...

Comment: Then [Paul Efford has the right answer for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59664918/3141792) below.

Answer (score 1):

There are various things to understand here:

1. Button control will have the DataContext set to MainWindowViewModel instance. This is the reason why ButtonText variable value is getting reflected in Button control text.
2. For ItemsControl the DataContext is the the same as for the Button, i.e. the MainWindowViewModel instance.
3. Each item in the ItemsControl ItemsSource acts as a DataContext for the elements in the ItemTemplate, i.e. the DockPanel and its child elements. This is managed automatically by the framework. So essentially you will need a public property named `ItemText` in the class which will act as a DataContext for Dockpanel.

In your case the ItemText property is not the part of the objects which are in list.

Comment: To your questions: (1 and 2) are desired behaviours set as per example to describe the issue with the binding inside the <ItemsSource>; (3) could you please let me know how? Thanks...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59664918/4749793 (@Paul Efford) provides the best explaination.